# how can i get files in any folders in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I trying to create a music player for a car with **qml** in the orange pi.
and in this project I need use get users' music with USB flash.

And in this USB there can be various files and folders. that we only need to get the audio files.

and this is part of my **qml** code:

```
MediaPlayer {
           id: player
           autoPlay: true


       }

       Item {
           id: playLogic

           property int index: -1
           property MediaPlayer mediaPlayer: player
           property FolderListModel items: FolderListModel {
               folder:  "./"
               nameFilters: ["*.mp3", "*.ogg", "*.wav"]
           }


           function init(){
               if(mediaPlayer.playbackState===1){
                   mediaPlayer.pause();
               }else if(mediaPlayer.playbackState===2){
                   mediaPlayer.play();
               }else{
                   setIndex(0);
               }
           }

           function setIndex(i)
           {
               index = i;

               if (index < 0 || index >= items.count)
               {
                   index = -1;
                   mediaPlayer.source = "";
               }
               else{
                   mediaPlayer.source = items.get(index,"filePath");
                   mediaPlayer.play();
               }
           }

           function next(){
               setIndex(index + 1);
           }

           function previous(){
               setIndex(index - 1);
           }
           Connections {
               target: playLogic.mediaPlayer

               onPaused: {
                   playpuse_img.source = puse;
               }

               onPlaying: {
                    playpuse_img.source = play;
               }

               onStopped: {
                   playpuse_img.source = play;
                   if (playLogic.mediaPlayer.status == MediaPlayer.EndOfMedia)
                       playLogic.next();
               }

               onError: {
                   console.log(error+" error string is "+errorString);
               }

               onMediaObjectChanged: {
                   if (playLogic.mediaPlayer.mediaObject)
                       playLogic.mediaPlayer.mediaObject.notifyInterval = 50;
               }
           }

       }
```

so for this idea, I think I need get any audio files in */media/$USER/{flas_name}* directory.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to do this purely in QML, then you are probably looking for a `FolderListModel`. See the docs [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html). Here's example usage:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.15

ListView {
    width: 200; height: 400

    FolderListModel {
        id: folderModel
        folder: "file:///media"
        nameFilters: ["*.mp3"]
    }

    Component {
        id: fileDelegate
        Text { text: fileName }
    }

    model: folderModel
    delegate: fileDelegate
}
```

Comment: hi, @JarMan Thank You For Your Answer :D
Your Idea is Not Working! because we no know what is flash name! 
the flas name can be anything!

Comment: Your question is not clear then. Your question was: *"I think I need get any audio files in /media/ directory."* My example shows how to get audio files from the media directory. Are you saying you want to be able to detect if a file is audio, even if it doesn't end with a ".mp3" or ".wav", etc?

Comment: so I min, I need to get any file in user USB flash with audio format.
You're right, USB flash is inside _/media/_ directory!
but I know not what is the name of the USB flash!

for example, USB flash name is test.
so now is easy to get audio files:

`FolderListModel {
        id: folderModel
        folder: "file:///media/$USER/test/"
        nameFilters: ["*.mp3"]
    }
`
But the hard part is that we do not know what the name of the USB flash drive is to be able to extract audio files!
so for this problem I trying to use the python backend with pyside2 library.
but i know no how